# I18n Rails list of supported locales (constants)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

So following is what I would like to do, be able to access I18n locale as a constant.For example:

```
if (I18n.locale == I18n.locales.en)
puts "You are using viewing page in english"
end
```

Is there a way to access these constants (I18n.locales.en is just example to clarify)? I can always write

```
if (I18n.locale.to_s == "en")
```

but I would like to avoid that. Since code is less readable with that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten your second statement to be `if (I18n.locale == :en)` rather than converting to a string, however that's still missing the point of using Rails' locale support. For example, with this yml file:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world!"
fr:
  hello: "Bonjour tout le monde !"
```

You should just be able to do this without any conditional statements:

```
puts I18n.translate(:hello)
```

and it would give you the appropriate translation.

If you really wanted to be able to do something like your first example, then you could override `method_missing` on the `Symbol` class. If you did this:

```
class Symbol
  def method_missing(method_name, *arguments)
    if method_name.to_s[-1,1] == "?"
      self.to_s == method_name.to_s[0..-2]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could do this:

```
if I18n.locale.en?
  puts "english"
end
```